# transformations of data structures with structural sharing

Tags: scala, functional-programming, structural-sharing

In functional programming, it's possible to save a large amount of memory by employing structural sharing. For instance, these two lists are the same, but the second is represented in memory in a much more efficient way:

```scala
val n = 4
// n: Int = 4
val l1 = List.tabulate(n)(x => (n-x until n).toList)
// l1: List[List[Int]] = List(List(), List(3), List(2, 3), List(1, 2, 3))
val l2 = List.unfold((n, List.empty[Int])) { case (i, l) =>
  if (i > 0) Some((l, ((i - 1), i - 1 :: l)))
  else None
}
// l2: List[List[Int]] = List(List(), List(3), List(2, 3), List(1, 2, 3))
```

But the moment you actually do something with `l2`, this advantage is quickly lost. Not only will the result of `l2.map(_.map(_ + 1))` require just as much memory as `l1`, it's also inefficient, because it will perform `n*(n-1)/2` additions, even though there's only `n-1` different numbers in this data structure.

With a mutable data structure this is easy: you can update the values in place, along with a marker that tells you whether the operation was already performed on that node. This way, you only traverse the data structure once, structural sharing is preserved and you only perform `n-1` additions.

But is there some elegant, functional way to achieve this without using mutable data structures?

Comment: Why do you say that the result of the `tabulate()` is different from the result of the `unfold()`? The [ScalaDocs](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List$.html#tabulate[A](n:Int)(f:Int=%3EA):CC[A]) page doesn't appear to indicate that.

Comment: Your mutable approach would only work if you are sure no one else also has a reference to `l2` or any of its inner lists. If you are completely sure about that then you can use some kind of mutable cell class like `final class MutableBox[A](var a: A)` and then having a `List[Cell[Int]]` instead, you would also need to keep a reference to the longest list since that is the one that needs to be updated. - However, you may actually be better with some kind of lazy view over the data, like why even compute the intermediate steps, only use the largest list and derive the other steps when required

Comment: To rephrase your question: "is there some elegant way to mutate things without them being mutable"? Perhaps, this way, the answer is more apparent?

Comment: Dima, That is not a rephrasing of my question but something you just made up. My real question is: is it possible to achieve the performance of the mutable solution (that is, linear performance rather than quadratic) without employing mutability?

Comment: @jwvh I believe the point is that in the `tabulate` version there are four separate inner lists created by four calls to `toList` while in the `unfold` version there is a single inner `List(1, 2, 3)` and earlier elements in the outer list are just the `tail` of later elements.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the mutable collections in the standard library don't take advantage of structural sharing, so you'd be implementing one on your own.

`l2`'s structural sharing is somewhat coincidental: a side effect of how it was built up.  It's not encoding the underlying structure (in this case that the `n`th element is the tail of the `n+1`th element with the last element being all the underlying elements).  But you can encode that structure fairly easily (I suspect it may be easier than with the mutable version).

Using the 2.13 APIs

```scala
case class TailsFirst[A](val elements: List[A]) extends Seq[List[A]] {
  def length: Int = 1 + elements.length

  def apply(idx: Int): List[A] = {
    require(idx < length)
    underlying.drop(elements.size - idx)
  }

  // useful for iteration, which will happen a lot (e.g. in toString)
  lazy val reverseElements: List[A] = elements.reverse

  def iterator(): Iterator[List[A]] =
    new Iterator[List[A]] {
      var state: Option[List[A]] = Some(reverseElements)
      var toEmit: List[A] = Nil

      def hasNext: Boolean = state.nonEmpty
      def next(): List[A] = {
        if (hasNext) {
          val ret = toEmit
          state.flatMap(_.headOption) match {
            case None =>
              assume(state.contains(Nil))  // hint for a mythical static analyzer
              state = None
              ret

            case Some(toPrepend) =>
              state = state.map(_.tail)
              toEmit = toPrepend :: toEmit
              ret 
          }
        } else throw new NoSuchElementException("exhausted iterator")

  def flatMapElements[B](f: A => List[B]): TailsFirst[B] =
    TailsFirst(elements.flatMap(f))

  def mapElements[B](f: A => B): TailsFirst[B] =
    TailsFirst(elements.map(f))
}
```